# OpenCV 4.x.x: How to implement SURF feature detector witout using opencv_contrib?

Tags: c++, opencv, surf

For an assignment I should use this tutorial for a task on feature detection and matching:
https://docs.opencv.org/3.2.0/d5/d6f/tutorial_feature_flann_matcher.html

However with version 4.0.1 installed and everything set up, I get the following error:

> Error (active)    E1696   cannot open source file "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"

As far as I could gather from different sources, is that the xfeatures2d module has been moved to the opencv_contrib repo. However, my assignment sheets states that the given example has been tested and should work with OpenCV 3.4.1. on a Linux system.

I have now downloaded and tested version 4.0.1, 3.4.6 and 3.4.1 all with the same result. The only difference is, that I work on Windows.

Is there a way to use this module without installing opencv_contrib? Is there a difference between the Windows and Linux versions?
If possible I want to avoid installing the opencv_contrib.

Comment: Since opencv 3 that has been moved to the contrib folder which is a separate install, this is because SURF is a patented feature, free for research and non-commercial usage but still a separate install.

Comment: According to [this blog post](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2015/07/16/where-did-sift-and-surf-go-in-opencv-3/) (the focus on Python is irrelevant), `SURF`, `SIFT`, and many other proprietary implementations have been moved to opencv_contrib. So, I highly doubt, that the linked tutorial works out-of-the-box for any pre-built Windows OpenCV 3.x.x distribution.

Comment: so there is now way around the opencv_contrib repo? It is weird, since my assignment sheet states, that is was tested with 3.4.1. Is there a difference to the Linux version? I run a dual-boot system, so I could switch, but I would only do so, if there is a chance of success.

Comment: Maybe, they tested it with their own built version of OpenCV 3.4.1, which maybe included all necessary packages!? But, in general: NO, there's no difference, it's the same library at all.

Comment: Can't I just somehow add the xfeature2d module to my existing 4.0.1 version, without having to install and build the complete master and contrib repo again?

Comment: How? The compiled library doesn't include the necessary features, so re-building this is an inevitable step.

Comment: OK, I guess I will have to install the opencv_contrib repo after all...

Comment: Did you try with the original SURF source code https://github.com/herbertbay/SURF?

Comment: @HerbertBay I did not, but in the meantime I learned that there is no way around installing the opencv_contrib lib to use these features. It was a PITA to get it working on Windows, but now everything does what it should. Cheers!

Comment: @RolandDeschain ok, cool, then I am happy that it works.